# Add LDAP entry to Active Directory via ext/ldap

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Using ext/ldap I'm trying to add entries to an Active Directory. As long as I only use one single structural objectClass everything works as expected, but as soon as I try to add an entry with a second auxiliary objectClass, the server reports an error:

> Server is unwilling to perform; 00002040: SvcErr: DSID-030F0AA0,
>   problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data
>   0

The following code works:

```
ldap_add($ldap, 'OU=Test,OU=Test,DC=domain,DC=example,DC=local', array(
    'ou' => 'Test',
    'objectClass' => 'organizationalUnit',
    'l' => 'location'
));
```

This doesn't:

```
ldap_add($ldap, 'OU=Test,OU=Test,DC=domain,DC=example,DC=local', array(
    'ou' => 'Test',
    'associatedDomain' => 'domain',
    'objectClass' => array('organizationalUnit', 'domainRelatedObject'),
    'l' => 'location'
));
```

The same happens if I try to add an auxiliary objectClass to an existing entry:

```
ldap_mod_add($ldap, 'OU=Test,OU=Test,DC=domain,DC=example,DC=local', array(
    'associatedDomain' => 'domain',
    'objectClass' => 'domainRelatedObject'
));
```

The corresponding error message is essentially the same

> Server is unwilling to perform;
>   00002040: SvcErr: DSID-030508F8,
>   problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data
>   0

As all other updating and adding operations work, I think the problem must be related to the objectClass attribute.

As I've not enough experience with Active Directories (I'm used to OpenLDAP):
Are there any known issues with objectClasses in Active Directory? Am I missing something here? Are there any restrictions that disallow adding e.g. `domainRelatedObject` to an `organizationalUnit`? What the heck 's going on here ;-)?

*Just in case you're wondering: the `domainRelatedObject` is present in the Active Directory schema.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that, in order to add dynamic (per-instance) aux classes, the [forest functional level of the domain must be 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676290.aspx).

Comment: Hi Martin!
Thanks a lot - that was the problem... I don't dare to think about the time I wasted on this one on the PHP side ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may not have permission to set the objectClass attribute. See whether you can attach the auxiliary class after creation, through [ADSI Edit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354.aspx). If you can't, fix the permissions first (check the Properties tab in the Advanced view of Security settings)

I could attach this specific class right now, onto a organizationalUnit object, as a domain admin; so in principle, this is possible.

Comment: Neither ADSI Edit nor ldp.exe will allow me to add the auxiliary class. ADSI Edit says "Die angegebene Methode wird nicht unterstützt" ("The specified method is not supported"). ldp.exe says: "Error: Modify: Ausführung verweigert. [...]

Comment: [...] <53>
Server error: 00002040: SvcErr: DSID-030F0AA0, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0"

This is the same even if I'm authenticated as a Domain Admin.

Comment: Hmm. What's the server? I was using W2k3SP2, and it worked fine.